# Comparison Clarification

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I would to hear the solution for the below requirement.

I have table A with key number and Fruits, table B with Fruits and rating with the below data. I have to retrieve result with least rating from B mapping keynumber A by based on fruits.

**My result should be like**

```
Keynumber   Fruits  Rating
123         Orange  4
456         Apricot 2
```

Table A

```
Key number  Country
123         Apple
123         Orange
456         Cherry
456         Apricot
```

Table B

```
Country Rating
Apple   5
Orange  4
Cherry  8
Apricot 2
```

I used the below query but it is displaying the two records of the same keynumber

```
select A."key number", A.fruits, B.fruits, B."rating from"
table A 
  left join table B on A.fruits = B.fruits 
order by a."key number"
```

```
Keynumber   Country Rating
123 Orange  4
123 Apple   5
456 Apricot 2
456 Cherry  8
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft sql sever management studio

Comment: May be you wanted to join on `keynumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @a table (Key_number int,  Country varchar(100));
insert into @a values
(123,         'Apple'),
(123,         'Orange'),
(456,         'Cherry'),
(456,         'Apricot');

declare @b table (Country varchar(100), Rating int);
insert into @b values
('Apple',   5),
('Orange',  4),
('Cherry',  8),
('Apricot', 2);

select top(1) with ties a.*, b.Rating
from @a a join @b b
        on a.Country = b.Country
order by row_number() over(partition by a.Key_number order by b.Rating);
```

Comment: Hi Team, Really you are so help full. I am able to find the solution with your help. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!! 1 question Can we you please explain  the function of " with ties"?